# Scope error instantiating object above setContentView Java

Tags: java, android, scope

I am trying to instantiate 3 objects to be used in a button event handler:

```
    // Instantiate class objects
    final TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.tp_selTime);
    final CheckBox cb_filterTime = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb_filterByTime);
    final DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dp_filterTime);
```

I start an activity from `MainActivity.java` called `FilterTimeActivity.java`. Obviously I need to do `super.onCreate` and `setContentView` before anything else, when I move the above 3 objects into the `public class FilterTimeActivity extends Activity {` but outside of the `OnCreate()` it crashes.

Is there a way to scope this correctly so I can access these objects from this method:

```
public void filterResults(View view){}
```

Which is called from a button listener (rather than being called from another method)

Comment: make this variables global and dont initialise them(i.e. outside onCreate), you can use them anywhere you want

Comment: Thanks for the comment, surly I have to initialise the object though?

Comment: Look at @Ken Wolf answer, that was what I meant..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declare them as member variables of your `Activity` (outside `onCreate()`).

Put these outside `onCreate()`, at the top of your class:

```
TimePicker timePicker;
CheckBox cb_filterTime;
DatePicker datePicker;
```

Then in `onCreate()`:

```
timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.tp_selTime);
cb_filterTime = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb_filterByTime);
datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dp_filterTime);
```

They are declared outside but initialised inside. You'll be able to use them anywhere.

Comment: Thanks! Sounds more simple than I was thinking, I will mark as accepted in a second :) would you mind explaining why this doesnt crash it, but instantiating them outside does?

Comment: `findViewById` requires `setContentView` and will otherwise return null. It's basically just how the system is set up to work.